# Webdriver can't locate the locators inside the frame

Tags: c#, iframe, selenium-webdriver

I am writing a framework for web application. Facing weird issue during the using of frames.
All webelements are declared as properties.

This a code snippet:

```
private  WebElement newOwner
    {
        get { return new WebElement().ById(Locators.btnNewOwnerID); }
    } 
public NewOwnerDialog OpenNewOwnerDialog()
    {
        //newOwner.Click();
        ClickWebElement(newOwner);
        return new NewOwnerDialog();
    }
public void ClickWebElement(WebElement webElement)
        {
            SwitchToPage();
            webElement.Click();
            QuitFrames();
        }

protected IWebDriverExt SwitchToPage()
        {
            if (!IsDriverOnTheFrame())
            {
                QuitFrames();
                SwitchFrame(FrameContainer);
            }
            return driver;
        }
```

I am using the page object model. I have menu navigation out of frame and the page's content inside the frame. 
  From my example you can see that I switched to frame before the usage of the weblement and left the frame after the usage. Before, I switched to frame when I navigated to the page and used elements inside, then left the frame.

The issue is: When I switched to frame for the first time, I could use all webelements inside, could perform all actions. **After I left the frame and then went back to it - webdriver could not see any locators, from debugging I can see that driver is inside the frame, but can not see the webelements.**

I have used different browsers, issue remains the same.

Could you please help me solve this issue.

I can provide additional info if you need.

Comment: after you switched out of iframe, what happened to it? did it close?

Comment: it will be nice to have your HTML source code as well as your program flow, e.g. you have provided us with methods, but how you executed your program? ***did you get any exception from selenium?***

Comment: Yes, I successfully navigated to the default content and used webelements out of the frame

Comment: Yes, I got timeout exception

Comment: @Paul Roub. Yes, I got an exception : Additional information: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:7055/hub/session/916d26ba-a97e-4494-89df-ad822382ee71/elements timed out after 60 seconds.